# CSS rotate cube to show different face EACH time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a cube with CSS and am trying to add a `:hover` action that rotates the cube in the X-axis 270 degrees each time. The problem I'm having is that once the rotation has finished the cube jumps back to it's original facing side. I'd like it to show a different face each time on a new `:hover`. Here is the jfiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/RuNpiXelruN/LLj0wfw2/

Please find the code below:

HTML :

```
<div class="cube-main">
      <div class="cube">
            <div class="face-1">
                Face One
            </div>
            <div class="face-2">
                Face 2
            </div>
            <div class="face-3">
                Face 3
            </div>
            <div class="face-4">
                Face 4
            </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
   .cube-main {
        perspective: 44vw;
        perspective-origin: 11vw 0vw;
        position: absolute;
        left: 51vw;
    }
    .cube {
        position: relative;
        height: 4vw;
        width: 18vw;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    .face-1, .face-2, .face-3, .face-4 {
        height: 4vw;
        width: 18vw;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .face-1 {
        background: red;
        transform: translateZ(2vw);
    }
    .face-2 {
        background: blue;
        transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-2vw);
        transform-origin: top center;
    }
    .face-3 {
        background: green;
        transform: translateZ(-2vw) rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .face-4 {
        background: yellow;
        transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(2vw);
        transform-origin: bottom center;
    }
    @keyframes spin {
        from { transform: rotateX(0); }
        to { transform: rotateX(270deg); }
    }

    .cube:hover {
        animation: spin 1s ease;
    }
```

The Fiddle  http://www.jsfiddle.net/RuNpiXelruN/LLj0wfw2

The cube looks just how I want it to, it's just the hover and showing a new face that i'm stuck on.

Thanks guys

Justin

Comment: maybe a fiddle would help :) http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @DriftingSteps Thanks for the suggestion. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/RuNpiXelruN/LLj0wfw2/  I'm happy for jQuery to be used also if it's an easier solution

Comment: So basically, once we hover on the cube, you want the cube to rotate from `face1` to `face3` and have it hold that position even after you hover out? Because once you hover out, the faces will reset back to the original, regardless of what error you have right now.

Comment: @DriftingSteps Yeah that's right. I'd like it to go from face 1 to face 3 and stay on face 3. Then on hover face 3 would rotate around to face 2 and stick on face 2 etc.

Comment: Okay, that may require some jquery help, as I don't think there's a css only solution for this. As for this current issue, I think I've found the reason behind it - http://i.imgur.com/vqVTXkU.png
Apparently, the `.cube` `div` also rotates with the `faces`.

Comment: @DriftingSteps Oh does that cause a problem do you think?..and yeah I'd love to know how to achieve this using jQuery but i'm not really sure where to begin.

Comment: I just found this script, although this might not be what you're looking for. It does have multiple faces that respond to certain states on-click. http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/3D-Box-Flip-Animation-with-jQuery-CSS3-turnBox-js/examples/confirm.html

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN: Just add a `forwards` for your animation to stop it reverting to the initial state while being hovered - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/LLj0wfw2/1/

Comment: @Abhitalks Thanks for that tip, i've added it, but do you know how to get it to STAY on that face? In this case the blue one, rather than reverting back to the red face?

Comment: @RuNpiXelruN: You are using `hover`. So, it will revert back once it is hovered off. You will need to use some other mechanism. One way of doing that - http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/LLj0wfw2/4/

Comment: @Abhitalks it's the same even with a checkbox. Plus I think he wants particularly on `:hover`.

Comment: Hi @DriftingSteps, and yeah you are right. I'm looking for a solution that works on :hover, and that sets a new face after each :hover action. Still unsure how to write jQuery that solves this? Thanks for all your answers though, I still have my fingers crossed that someone can help me out!